# something is going wrong when using 'try & except' in PYCHARM . 'except' is not workig. it give me 'f is not definded'

Tags: python, try-catch, except

```py
try:
  f = open("demofile.txt")
  f.write("Lorum Ipsum")
except:
  print("Something went wrong when writing to the file")
finally:
  f.close()
```

Comment: Code in `finally` will be executed anyway, it doesn't matter did exception occurred or not. Seems like you got an exception on `open()` call, so `f` haven't been defined, but you try to access it and get another exception. Read: [*Handling Exceptions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: not working at all. it give me error

Comment: Yes @OlvinRoght is right. As you are not passing mode type "w".

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run the below code. You have not passed the mode type. If any exception occurs, comment here.

```
try:
    f = open("demofile.txt", "w")
    f.write("Lorum Ipsum")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    f.close()
```

You can also use 'with' here. Because this method will automatically close the opened file after file operations are done.

```
with open("demofile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Lorum Ipsum")
```

Comment: What if file is locked by OS?

Comment: @Olvin Rought then open() will throw IOError

Comment: And code in `finally` will throw an error.

Comment: So, if he really wants to get rid of this error, wants to ensure that the file should be closed even if exception occurs then use `with open`.

Comment: So why don't you make it happen in your answer?